# Proper way to present UIActivityViewController inside UINavigationController inside popup

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

Suppose I have a `UINavigationController` inside a `UIPopup`. From there, I try to present a `UIActivityViewController`, by pushing it into the view controller.

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController{
    navigationController.pushViewController(activityViewController, animated: true)
}else{
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The code executes without errors, however:

1. The displayed `UIActivityViewController` is corrupted and some text is not visible. (See image)
2. While pushing the view, part of the screen flashes when the popup resizes to accommodate the view (the popover is in the right side of the screen, and a ~150px vertical strip becomes brighter on the left)

As far as I know, I do not break Apple's Human Interface Guidelines by presenting the view this way. If so, what can be done so the view displays flawlessly?

[image: The displayed UIActivityView, note the missing text]

Comment: I got this problem too.